# Почему событие дисконнект работает не правильно в socket.io?

Tags: node.js

**Есть вполне себе обычная структура на node.js + socket.io:**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('add user', function(hash, interlocutor_id) {

  });

  socket.on('private message', function(from, msg) {

  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {

  });
});
```

Это используется в небольшом кастомном чате. 
Проблема состоит в следующем:
Когда я зажимаю ф5, через 20 - 40 коннектов, событие дисконект перестает работать и в комнатах появляются дубли (так как событие дисконект отвечает за очистку комнат).

Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно решить?

Answer (score 1):

Можно установить таймаут примерно так:

```
var io = require('socket.io')({
  'timeout': 5000 //set the timeout to 5s
});
```

Comment: К сожалению кпд 0 =(